# iOS 9 / Xcode 7: SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed not working on some devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit, ios9

I am having problems to load a image from a .xcassets imageset for a SKSpriteNode.

While it worked fine on iOS 8.x with *[SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamde:imageName]* it doesn't work on some devices on iOS 9. For example it works on iPhone 6/6 Plus and iPad Air but not on the iPod Touch 5G.

Works on all devices with iOS 8.x but not on all devices (for example iPod Touch 5g) on iOS 9.x (Xcode 7, Xcode 7.1 Beta 3):

```
SKSpriteNode *background = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"MenuBackgroundImage"];
background.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
background.zPosition = 100;
[self addChild:background];
```

The interesting thing is that it works on iOS 9 if I load the image like this:

```
SKTexture *imageTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MenuBackgroundImage"]];
SKSpriteNode* background = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:imageTexture];
```

The problem is that if I load the image with UIImage that the internal caching won't work. Does anybody know how to load a ImageSet from a .xcassets in iOS 9 correctly so that it works on ALL devices?

Comment: The same bug is described here: https://openradar.appspot.com/22737731 

This bug still exists with iOS 9.1 Beta 4. This is absolute ridiculous that Apple can't fix this issue within several iOS 9.x releases (betas included). MANY games are affected with this bug and the workaround is not really a good solution.

Comment: It seems that this bug only occurs on 32-bit devices (iPad mini, iPhone 4s, iPhone 5, iPod Touch 5g) etc. I've already filed a bug report about this issue to Apple.

Comment: I had the same problem and solved it by changing my images from jpg to png. Not sure if this is the root cause of this issue. Maybe I fixed it by just adding all images again.